# Not able to update specifc DataTable in DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable, sqldataadapter

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from record",@"database=student;server=arun-pc\mypc;integrated security=true");
      da.Fill(ds,"record");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from emp";
      da.Fill(ds,"emp");
      dataGrid1.DataSource = ds;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
      da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
      MessageBox.Show("updated")
}
```

I'm not able to update `table[0]` but I can update in `table[1]` and I'm not able to find why it is so?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem and did you debug your code?

Comment: Check that user has update permission on table. Also, use try/catch block to get any exception.

Comment: Any error message shows or it just silently executes over it (the line) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot easier for you if you follow these tutorials here when doing your data access (be sure to choose your .net version if you're not on 2.0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6(v=vs.80).aspx

Start with the "Creating a Simple Data App" one

As to what is actually going wrong, if all you're finding is that no rows are being updated (update returns 0) then you should first check that the table you're sending for update actually contains modified rows..

Follow the tutorial, and do your data access that away and it will either all work out, or you'll get an error message that tells you where things went wrong :)

Comment: finaly i found my answer "a single data adpter can update a singe table ,and i was using the two table in data set ,so it was only update the table[1] . the last one "  thanx for your responces